# Differences in relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have **three** tables:

- users
- realizations
- realization_user

**User Model:**

```
public function realizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Realization::class)->withPivot('status', 'payment');
}
```

**Realization Model:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps()->withPivot('status', 'payment');
}
```

Logged user is attached only to one realization, when I want to show numbers of his realizations I do sth like this:

```
$user->realizations->count()
```

and I get result: 1, but when I do this:

```
$user->with('realizations')->count()
```

I get 13.

What is wrong? And how to add eg. whereHas on this relations?

Answer (score 2):

In 1st case you are getting count of user realizations, but in 2nd you are getting users count.

To get only realizations count you can use:

```
$user->realizations()->count()
```

or in case you need also realizations you can use:

```
$user->realizations->count()
```

Keep in mind there is a difference which one you choose. If for user you have 1 mln realizations, the first one will execute query to database to get only count of realizations and the 2nd one will take all realizations from database and then calculates their number.

Comment: Hmm, so how I can narrow results by realization columns? How to add to this whereHas?

Comment: I want to get for example number of user all relizations which one start in next week.

Comment: You can use `$user->realizations()->where(// here you put condition you want)->count()`